# Perforce ticket to be less than 12 hours

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to set the Perforce ticket time to be less than 12 hours or is 12 hours the minimal value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You can set it manually in the group spec.

Example:

```
Group: GroupName
Timeout: 300 // duration in second
Users:
       User1
       User2
       User3
```